# Удаление из файла

Tags: delphi, файлы

Здравствуйте, такая проблема: нужно удалить определенную запись в файле. Я делаю таким образом: сперва удаляю елемент в динамическом массиве, а потом пытаюсь переписать этот массив заново в файл. Но у меня вылетает ошибка: Range check error. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```
Procedure delStud(var stud:TArr);
var
  filename:string;
  i,ind:integer;
begin

  write('Введите порядковый номер студента: '); readln(ind);
  for i:= ind to high(stud) do
    stud[i-1] := stud[i];
  SetLength(stud,length(stud)-1);

  filename:=('H:\2 sem\progr\lab_works\Laba3\studMain.bin');
  AssignFile(f1,filename);
  Reset(f1);
  i:=0;
  while (not Eof(f1)) and (i < Length(stud)) do
  begin
    write(f1, stud[i]);
    i:=i+1;
  end;
Closefile(f1);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Минус 1 забыли:

```
  for i := ind to Length(stud) - 1 do
```

Внутрь `while` программа не попадет, потому что сразу выйдет по условию `(not Eof(f1))`, так как перед этим был `Reset(f1)` и файл стал нулевой длинны.

```
Reset(f1);
i := 0;
while (i < Length(stud)) do
begin
  write(f1, stud[i]);
  i := i + 1;
end;
```

Comment: По-моему, тут не нужен -1, так как я же делаю "stud[i-1] := stud[i]", а -1 пригодился бы если бы я делал что-то вроде "stud[i+1] := stud[i]" или я все-таки неправ? 

Не очень понял, почему файл стал нулевой длинны :( Если вы подразумеваете использование Reset`а, то при типизированном файле (какой я использую) все вроде-бы должно оставаться, как и было (содержание и размер).
З.Ы.: попробовал прикрепить и ваш код, и приделать -1, в итоге та же ошибка

Comment: Reset открывает файл на R/W доступ (если существует) и падает если файла нет. Позиция в файле становится нулевой, а не eof. При таком коде вы получите накопление данных в файле с вставкой в начало файла. Для обнуления файла надо делать Rewrite.

Comment: @111xbot111 Элементы массива нумеруются с нуля. Если в массиве 2 элемента, то их номера 0 и 1. `Length(stud)` вернет значение 2. При попытке прочитать из массива элемент с номером 2 в лучшем случае получится "Range check error". Насчет файла я ошибся.
Уточните в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, в исходном варианте цикл не до Length(stud), а до High(stud), что соответствует Length-1.  
@111xbot111, Ошибка может быть только если 0 элемент попробовать удалить, тогда будет присваивание stud[-1]:=stud[0]

Comment: @kot-da-vinci , я понимаю, что эл-ты начинаются с нуля, спасибо) В общем, вы мне правильно посоветовали, спасибо, но  у меня есть одна проблемка: оно не хочет делать стирание и кидает ошибку, если я перед этим не создам студента (там еще одна процедура) или не сделаю поиск студента. Какая-то вакханалия: я уже и так, и эдак код переставлял, результата нет. Пока еще сам попытаюсь с этой штукой повозится, если все-таки не справлюсь, то завтра уже буду просить помощи.